# PDO bindParam truncate string after double quote

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a problem with PDO prepare query. When I try to insert a simple string with double quotes like this **'example string " to be inserted in mysql'**, the query result is truncated when the double quotes start and the result in MySQL is **'example string'**.
Does anyone had this problem with pdo?

This is my query:

```
    $sql = "UPDATE sales 
        SET note = :note
        WHERE id_sale= :id";

    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':note', $this->note, PDO::PARAM_STR, 80);
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $this->id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

    $stmt->execute();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Escape it in your string `'example string \" to be inserted in mysql'`

Comment: I have already tried to escape especial characters with php functions and PDO::quote(), but the problem continues. I don't know if is a PDO bug, but is very strange.

Comment: what's the exact code you used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to escape the quotes properly depending on the underlying database.

PDO can do this for you, check out [PDO::quote](http://php.net/manual/de/pdo.quote.php).

```
$string = 'Example string';

print "Quoted string: " . $conn->quote($string);
```

Output will be

> Quoted string: 'Example string'